# Generate user Oauth2 token from Store, Google Federated Authenticator - WSO2 AM 2.0.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, google-authentication

In API Manager 2.0.0 I have configure a federated authenticator for oauth2, setting-up with a google authentication, and configure a service provider for an application to use this federated authenticator. Then I follow the tutorial [1] in order to use this application with the google authentication.

When I try to generate the keys from the Store portal using Code or Implicit grant types, the server give me the following error:

> Error occurred while calling token endpoint: HTTP error code : 400

and in the log shows:

> {"error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid","error":"invalid_grant"}

---

Can anyone help me with this problem? How can I configure a federated authenticator to consume te APIs/Applications?

Thanks.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byg9oNMYKYmRLUx0dVVzV2xrMjQ/view?usp=sharing) you can see the debug log of APIM.

[1] http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/04/28/federated-authentication-for-granting-oauth2-access-token-with-wso2-api-manager-apim/

Comment: Can you attach a wso2 apim log created during the issue time?

Comment: Hi nwick, I have add the log to the original question, thanks.

Comment: When `Provided Authorization Grant is invalid` while getting oauth token, enable debug log for `org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2` package. You can get more specific root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Service Provider doesn't allow Implicit and Code grants by default.

To change this log into carbon on `Service Providers` -> `List`. Choose your SP and then click on `Edit`.

In the edit page, go to `Inbound Authentication Configuration` -> `OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration`. Your application key and secret should be listed here, the one that you generate on the store.

Click on `edit`, this will bring all the OAuth grants available. Probably Code and Implicit are unchecked. Check them and click on `Update`, you should be able to generate tokens using both grants now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel, but it doesn't work. I try enable the Code or Implicit grand types from Store portal and Carbon portal, but I get the same error.
I've done with the external test webapp [playground](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/OAuth+2.0+with+WSO2+Playground) but not from the Store portal. It seems like the Store portal allways send the client_credentials grand type instead of code or implicit.